# Returning a filtered list of iPhones

Tags: javascript, strings, unit-testing, interview-questions, ecmascript-6

I have just received feedback regarding a junior dev test that I submitted. It was unfortunately not great, and the recruiter could not articulate the issues, I tried to show that I was thinking about the problem in a deeper way, but the feedback was that the solution was "over complicated".

**This is the challenge:**

```
// Complete the functions below

// You should run this function to return a filtered list of iphones
function filterBySearchTerm(iphones, Gold) {
    return iphones.filter(doFilter);
}

// Complete this function to use the 'searchTerm' argument to return an iphone that matches the 'searchTerm'
// -- You should match the `color` and `capacity` fields.
//    e.g. if I use the search term 'Gold' this should return true for iphones that have a color value of 'Rose Gold' and 'Gold', if I use the search term '64' this should return true for iphones where the capacity is value of '64GB'
function doFilter() {
    return iphone => iphone;
}
```

**The sub requirements given by the recruiter were:**

> The things in which they are looking for in the homework task is the quality of your code, some obvious unit testing, the presentation and the UI. Like we discussed they are looking for people who are wanting to go above and beyond when doing the homework task, if there's any extra features you can incorporate or extra unit tests you can do, then definitely include them along with a description of the highlights of your code.

**Here is my submission:**

I wanted to allow searching through fuzzy matching of the search string against the input search string. I thought if I split the string and did the search on each word it would provide more results for the end user.

There was no unit testing available and no way to include it so I created a basic clone of Jasmine. Was this a bad move?. it adds more than double the code to the solution. but it should show that I have technical ability, and can understand javascript beyond a beginner level.

```js
// had to throw in a hack to make the console logging work in the repl
// this will be a little prettier in the browser.
const __repl__ = 'repl';
const __browser__ = 'browser';

const __environment = __repl__;

if( __environment === __repl__ ){
  console.group = console.log;
  console.groupEnd = () => {};
}

/**
 * stringToFuzzyRegex :: String -> RegExp
 *
 * convert an input string into a fuzzy Regular expression
 *
 * @param {String}  str
 *
 * @returns {RegExp}
 */
const stringToFuzzyRegex = ( str ) => {
  return new RegExp( '.*' + str.split('').join('.*') + '.*', 'i' );
}


/**
 * flatten :: Array -> Array
 *
 * recursively flatten a multidimensional array into a single Array
 *
 * @param  {Array}  arr
 *
 * @returns {Array}
 */
const flatten = ( arr ) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
    return Array.isArray(x)
      ? acc.concat( flatten( x ) )
      : acc.concat( x );
  }, []);
}

/**
 * unique :: Array -> Array
 *
 * strip out duplicate entries of an Array
 *
 * @param  {Array}  arr
 *
 * @returns {Array}
 */
const unique = ( arr ) => {
  return arr.reduce(( acc, x ) => {
    return acc.indexOf( x ) < 0
      ? acc.concat( x )
      : acc;
  }, []);
}

/**
 * filterByReg :: RegExp -> iphone -> Boolean
 *
 * this function will curry a regular expression waiting for on object with
 * color and capacity properties.
 *
 * @param {RegExp}  regex  pattern to test iphone properties
 * @param {iphone}  iphone  iphone object
 *
 * note:
 *   if the requirments on which fields are required for searching changes
 *   this is the only function that will need to change.
 *
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
const filterByReg = ( regex ) => {
  return function doFilter( iphone ){
    return !!(iphone.color.match(regex) || iphone.capacity.match(regex));
  };
}


/**
 * filterBySearchTerm :: ( iphones -> String ) -> Array
 *
 * filter a list of iphones by a search string
 *
 * @param {Array<iphone>}  iphones  array of iphone objects
 * @param {String}  searchTerm  string to filter iphones by
 *
 * @returns {Array}
 */
const filterBySearchTerm = (iphones, searchTerm) => {

  // allow searching for multiple options at the same time
  // seperated by a space
  const results = searchTerm.split(' ')
    .map(stringToFuzzyRegex)
    .map(( reg ) => {
      return iphones.filter( filterByReg(reg) );
    });

  // the result is a multidimensional array with duplicates
  // they need to be filtered out before being returned
  return unique(flatten(results));
}

const iphones = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "iPhone SE",
    "color": "Silver",
    "type": "Wifi",
    "capacity": "16GB",
    "price": 629
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "iPhone SE",
    "color": "Silver",
    "type": "Wifi",
    "capacity": "64GB",
    "price": 829
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "iPhone SE",
    "color": "Gold",
    "type": "Wifi",
    "capacity": "16GB",
    "price": 629
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "iPhone SE",
    "color": "Gold",
    "type": "Wifi",
    "capacity": "64GB",
    "price": 829
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "iPhone SE",
    "color": "Space Grey",
    "type": "Wifi",
    "capacity": "16GB",
    "price": 629
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "iPhone SE",
    "color": "Space Grey",
    "type": "Wifi",
    "capacity": "64GB",
    "price": 829
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "iPhone SE",
    "color": "Rose Gold",
    "type": "Wifi",
    "capacity": "16GB",
    "price": 629
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "iPhone SE",
    "color": "Rose Gold",
    "type": "Wifi",
    "capacity": "64GB",
    "price": 829
  }
];

/** Expect Object for unit testing  **/
class Expect {
  constructor( expression ){
    this.expression = expression;
  }

  toEqual(value){
    const type = toString( value );
    log( this.expression === value, `expected to equal ${value}` );
  }

  toMatch( value ){
    log( !!this.expression.test( value ), `expected to match in ${value}` );
  }

  toBeArray(){
    log( Array.isArray( this.expression ), `expected to be an Array`);
  }

  toBeInstance( instance ){
    log( this.expression instanceof instance, `expected instance of ${instance.name}` );
  }
}

/** UNIT TESTS **/

describe('stringToFuzzyRegex', ( it, expect ) => {

  const reg = stringToFuzzyRegex('bar');

  it('should convert a String to a Regular Expression', () => {
    expect( reg ).toBeInstance( RegExp );
  });

  it('should match the word "bar" at any position in a string', () => {
    expect( reg ).toMatch('bar');
    expect( reg ).toMatch('foobar');
    expect( reg ).toMatch('barbaz');
    expect( reg ).toMatch('foobarbaz');
  });

  it('should fuzzy match the word "bar" anywhere within a string', () => {
    expect( reg ).toMatch('__b__a__r__');
    expect( reg ).toMatch('xxxbxxxaxxxrxxx');
  });

  it('should do a non case sensitive match', () => {
    expect( reg ).toMatch('fOoBaRbAz');
  });
});


describe('flatten', ( it, expect ) => {

  const arr = [1,[2,[3],4],5];
  const flattened = flatten(arr);

  it('should take and return an Array', () => {
    expect( arr ).toBeArray();
    expect( flattened ).toBeArray();
  });

  it('should flatten a multidimensional array to a single array', () => {
    expect( arr.length ).toEqual(3);
    expect( flattened.length ).toEqual(5);
  });
});

describe('unique', ( it, expect ) => {

  const one = {name: 'one'};
  const two = {name: 'two'};
  const three = {name: 'three'};
  const objectArray = unique([ one, two, three, one, two ]);
  const numberArray = unique([1, 2, 3, 1, 2]);
  const mixedArray = unique([1, one, 2, two, 3, three, 1, one, 2, two]);

  it('should take and return an Array', () => {
    expect( objectArray ).toBeArray();
  });

  it('should strip out duplicate array entries', () => {
    expect( objectArray.length ).toEqual(3);
    expect( numberArray.length ).toEqual(3);
    expect( mixedArray.length ).toEqual(6);
  });
});

describe('filterByReg', ( it, expect ) => {

  const iphoneMock = { color: 'gold', capacity: '64GB' };

  it('should filter the iphones based on color and capacity', () => {
    expect(filterByReg(/gold/)( iphoneMock )).toEqual(true);
    expect(filterByReg(/64*/)( iphoneMock )).toEqual(true);
  });
});

describe('filterBySearchTerm', ( it, expect ) => {

  const iphonesMock = [
    { color: 'gold', capacity: '64GB' },
    { color: 'gold', capacity: '32GB' },
    { color: 'white', capacity: '64GB' },
    { color: 'white', capacity: '32GB' },
    { color: 'black', capacity: '64GB' },
    { color: 'black', capacity: '32GB' }
  ];

  it('should take and return an Array', () => {
    expect( iphonesMock ).toBeArray();
    expect( filterBySearchTerm(iphonesMock, 'gold') ).toBeArray();
  });

  it('should filter down the results based on color or capacity properties', () => {
    expect( filterBySearchTerm(iphonesMock, 'gold').length ).toEqual(2);
    expect( filterBySearchTerm(iphonesMock, '64').length ).toEqual(3);
    expect( filterBySearchTerm(iphonesMock, 'gold 64').length ).toEqual(4);
  });
});


/** UTILITIES **/

/**
 * describe
 *
 * this is a simple test suite mocking up the popular test suites available.
 *
 * I am using the old function declaration style as I purposely want the function to
 * hoist to the top of the file
 *
 * @param {String}  name  identifier or the test
 * @param {Function}  suite  test function
 *
 * @returns void 0
 */
function describe( name, suite ) {

  /**
   * it
   *
   * @param {String}  description  spec description
   * @param {Function}  spec  spec callbacks
   *
   * @returns void 0
   */
  const it = ( description, spec ) => {
    console.group( 'it ' + description );
    spec();
    console.groupEnd();
  }

  /**
   * expect
   *
   * assertion function that takes the value of an expression
   *
   * @param {*}  expression  expression to assert
   *
   * @returns {Expect}
   */
  function expect( expression ){
    return new Expect( expression );
  }

  console.group( '\n--> ' + name );
  suite( it, expect );
  console.groupEnd( name );
}

/**
 * log
 *
 * make an assertion log to the console
 *
 * @param {*}  expression  any expression or value that evaluates to truthy
 * @param {String}  description  description for the console
 *
 * @returns void 0
 */
function log( expression, description ){

  let testHeading = null;

  if( __environment !== __repl__ ){
   testHeading = !!expression
    ? ['%c PASS ', 'background:green;color:white']
    : ['%c FAIL ', 'background:red;color:white'];
  } else {
   testHeading = !!expression
    ? [' [PASS] ']
    : [' [FAIL] '];
  }

  console.log.apply( console, testHeading.concat( description ) );
}

/**
 * toString
 *
 * get the string representation of a value
 *
 * @param  {*}  thing  any value
 *
 * @returns {String}
 */
function toString( thing ){
  switch( thing ){
    case null:
      return 'null';
    case undefined:
      return 'undefined';
    default:
      return thing.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should better apply for a job without the "junior" prefix ;)

Comment: I kept getting turned down before I even got to speak with anyone as I don't have the experience on paper. They all want Professional Angular experience which I have none cause I work for a company that still has 10 year old tech. Recruiters see my Resume and put me on the 'no' pile. This was the first actual test I have had for a position so I wanted to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

business people, want things to get done! Not a research project ;)
Maybe something like this, would make them more happy :)

```
function filterBySearchTerm(iphones, searchTerm) {
    return iphones.filter(doFilter, new RegExp(searchTerm, "i"));
}

function doFilter(iphone) {
    return this.test(iphone.color) || this.test(iphone.capacity);
}
```

Comment: They gave me a second attempt and this is pretty much what I ended up going with, but I just used toLowerCase and indexOf. I'm pretty sure I won't get the job, the hardest think was going back and forth on whether to user RegExp. I assumed that was the main problem.

Comment: What was your final arguments, not to use `RegExp`?

Comment: However, in an interview, its normal to feel nervous and make emotional decisions :) 
If you really want the job, just send them a third approach, and tell them you are not sure, but you know how it can work in different ways, don't be scared it's just a job in a year you probably will hate it :D

Comment: It wasn't even an interview, just a pre interview skills test. The test is online though so I looked at every other entry and they were all the most basic answer that could be given if they even worked at all. I think it's for the best because if they didn't like that they would hate when I use actually complicated code. I'm not sure what I learn't from the experience. But I don't want to and probably couldn't make compromises on quality if I tried.

Comment: You learned, that `business !== quality` ;) If you depend on an your employer, then you should think about his satisfaction rather then on your coder ambitions

Comment: I have to maintain horrible spaghetti code that was done to make the quickest buck with the least amount of thought possible... from my limited professional experience I honestly believe `longTermMaintainableBusiness == quality`. The code I showed above is more of a simple application that is reusable and could be put into a bigger system, and the actual application part of it is only around 10 lines that are high level and pretty easy to understand, I never took the test as a simple function. I thought that would be a trick to thin the list of candidates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41413/discussion-between-webdeb-and-synthet1c).

Answer (score 1):

If I were interviewing you, this submission would impress me a lot.

My guess is that they were looking for something simple: the shortest possible solution to the problem at hand, which admittedly could be done in 10 lines or fewer.  What's confusing is that they *specifically asked* for you to go above and beyond, which you did with the Jasmine clone and the fuzzy matching feature.

The code itself is functional, readable, and easy to understand.  Anyone who thinks the code itself is too complicated doesn't know modern JS and isn't, imo, someone you'd want to work for.  The only valid complaints about this submission are 1) reinventing the wheel (making a Jasmine clone rather than using Jasmine) and 2) add your own additional requirements rather than solving the problem given as efficiently as possible.

But you said that for 1) you had not choice and for 2) they requested that you do this.  I'm inclined to chalk this up to a poor interviewer...

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I'm thinking along the lines of what you are saying. I don't think I really want to work for a company that doesn't understand modern js. On reinventing the wheel... I was using repl.it which has no plugins so there was no choice but to have something to do unit testing. Making a jasmine clone was a bit overboard when a console.log would suffice, but  I thought it would be good to show that I understand es6 classes and it was only a few lines more.